# using create-react-app I get EEXIST: file already exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npx

I am making my first react app and running command: `npx create-react-app my-app` and i am getting this error:

`Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\Deepak'`

`command not found: create-react-app`

Can anybody please help me to resolve this error?

Answer (score 5):

Follow these steps, it will definitely work:

1. `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
2. `npm install -g create-react-app`
3. `npx create-react-app the-name-of-your-app`

Answer (score 1):

I do have space in my UserName folder so I tried this
run the command

```
npm config edit
```

set the variable `cache=C:\Users\{UserName}` and save the file

This work in my case, hope it will help u too

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a my-app folder/directory in `C:\Users\Deepak`. Could you try as below?

`npx create-react-app my-super-app`

Comment: This doesn't work i also have gap between name of my user folder i.e          
 C:\Users\Deepak rawat\Desktop\New folder   in Deepak rawat can this be a problem??

Comment: @061_Deepak Singh Rawat- yes it can be the case too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a space in your users directory `Deepak`. That is the most common reason for this type of error.

`NPX` uses `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache` while executing. It has a bug which prevents it from running if there is space in this path.

To remedy this problem you need to update the npm cache path by replacing the string after the space with `~1`

**E.g.**

`npm config set cache C:\Users\Deepak~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`

This will set npm cache path without the space.

After this if you run npx it should work fine without throwing any error.

**NOTE:** You might want to run this command and the npx command with administrative rights or you might get permission error